# Looping spool scripts

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a big table in an Oracle database, which I would like to extract to CSV so I can move it onto another system (ideally there would be a direct connection between these two systems, but in the absence of that this is the next best solution).

Because the table is large, I'm extracting a month of data at the time. So the query looks like this:

```sql
set termout off;
set echo off;
set verify off;
spool "C:\output_path\&&1. events.csv";
select /*csv*/ * from my_database.events
where my_date between to_date(&&1,'yyyy-mm-dd') and to_date(&&2,'yyyy-mm-dd');
spool off
set termout on;
set echo on;
```

I then call this from another script, like so:

```
@my_script.sql "'2020-01-01'" "'2020-01-31'"
```

This would put "2020-01-01" and "2020-01-31" in place of &&1 and &&2 respectively, and output January's data to `C:\output_path\'2020-01-01' events.csv`.

Ideally I'd like to turn this into a loop, so I could have a function like this (pseudo-python):

```py
def scrape_range_of_months(start_date, end_date)
    date_range = make_date_range(start_date, end_date)
    for date in date_range:
        scrape_month(date, end_of_month(date))
```

Where make_date_range() and end_of_month() are separate functions.

PL/SQL is a far more arcane language than Python though, so while I can find individual parts of solutions, it's not clear if it's even possible to run scripts on a loop like I'd like to.

Comment: 1) PL/SQL is no more arcane than any other language you are not fluent in.  It is actually built on ADA, itself derived from Pascal.  2) If there is not a direct connection between the systems, how to you propose to get your csv files there?  FedEx a DVD?  3) how big is 'big'.  4) If you get this in a single, looping,script producing multiple csv files that constitute a 'set', what's the advantage of that over a single csv file?

Comment: Does it have to be a `SQL*Plus` script?  PL/SQL allows looping and has the `utl_file` package which would let you create a file on the database server.  I'm not completely sure why you're breaking up the data in the first place-- it's going to take longer to extract the data month-by-month than it will to do it in a single pass.  And it'll be more work to load it in again.  Unless the table is so big that a single file would exceed the maximum file size allowed by your operating system or something like that...

Comment: *it's not clear if it's even possible to run scripts on a loop* - PL/SQL can't run SQL\*Plus scripts at all. It's a programming language that runs within the database.

Comment: @EdStevens 1) the limited online tutorials (as compared to e.g. Python) makes it harder to grok for a novice, but obviously ymmv. 2) literally drag+drop the files from file system into Amazon S3. Unfortunately the best solution in the circumstances (at least until a better system comes online) 3) like 200-500m records. 4) repeating extracts as new data comes in. While other tables are small enough to extract in one go, these tables are too big. Also breaking it up means that if there's a crash, I don't lose (as much) progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@justin Cave is right, a full solution would use UTL_FILE to write the files directly from PL/SQL.

In this example I have written some PL/SQL to generate the code to do a month by month extract. I change the "between" to ">=" and "<" because if there were a time component you would miss records for the last day of the month.

```
DECLARE
    l_date    DATE := DATE '2020-01-01';
    c_spool   VARCHAR2( 512 ) := Q'[spool "C:\output_path\YMD.events.csv";
select /*csv*/ * from my_database.events
where my_date >= to_date('YMD','yyyy-mm-dd') and my_date < add_months(to_date('YMD','yyyy-mm-dd'),1);
]';
BEGIN
    WHILE l_date < SYSDATE
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( REPLACE( c_spool
                                     , 'YMD'
                                     , TO_CHAR( l_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd' ) ) );
        l_date   := ADD_MONTHS( l_date, 1 );
    END LOOP;
END;
```

example output:

```
spool "C:\output_path\2020-02-01.events.csv";
select /*csv*/ * from my_database.events
where my_date >= to_date('2020-02-01','yyyy-mm-dd') and my_date < 
add_months(to_date('2020-02-01','yyyy-mm-dd'),1);
```

Comment: This is great, and does most of what I want. The next step would be another script (or another line in this one) to run the code it generated). I guess that's where UTL_FILE would come in?